# Composition is not working (no render, no file)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I need a setup, where I render an object with transparent background but with reflection.

This is my setup (composition). The picture in the viewer is like expected. If I press F12 I get no file in the tmp folder and a "wrong" picture will be renderd (with plane). Compostion is activated, but its somehow ignored. Does someone has a tip?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5867" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5867/)

Answer (score 1):

To see result of compositing switch *Layer* viewer to `Composite` in *Image Editor*

[image]